# Using Python and QT Designer on a MAC can't get menus to show up

Tags: python, qt

I have seen several posts to correct this bug  whereby the menus do not work  properly on the mac main menu bar  by using the command
menubar.setNativeMenuBar(False). This basically makes the menu appear on the QMainWindow as it does in Windows which is OK for my application.
But I want to use the QT designer generated code and I would like to
set this as the default  option or do I have to edit the generated code
each time I rerun the Designer? Thanks for any help,

Comment: Thank you for bringing it up. I ran into the same problem with PyQT5 on my MacBook (macOS Mojave 10.14) and need help too. Currently, I use toolbar instead of menubar as a workaround.

Comment: That's a good idea. I also discovered that the names of the items in the menus are an issue. If you choose 'File' for the first entry that seems to work, but if you choose 'Exit' for the next entry it doesn't  but 'Leave' does. So I guess its some conflict with MAC OS .